# Can't load OSX after installing Boot camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, imac

My bootcamp installation seems to have failed and I can't get back to OSX by holding option key on my wired keyboard for iMac at reboot. What else can I do? Please help.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix this with a different keyboard I think some keyboards aren't recognized immediately on startup. Deleting bootcamp right away before it bricks my mac.

Comment: What kind of keyboard is it? It should be able to recognize any even vaguely standard USB keyboard at startup (wireless keyboards are trickier).